R: How would I use lavaan in R to create a latent longitudinal growth curve model with a binary outcome?
I am specifying a latent longitudinal growth curve model in R with multiple time-invariant covariates. However, my outcome is binary (0/1). I read through the growth() function documentation, but didn't find anything specific to my situation. I know it's statistically possible, but was wondering if anything needs to be done with syntax to account for the outcome.
